# Dynamics CRM xrm.cs compile error

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I'm trying to connect to CRM using steps declared in this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx

**Error**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Services.IUpdatable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Source Error:


Line 192816:    /// </summary>
Line 192817:    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CrmSvcUtil", "7.0.0000.3543")]
Line 192818:    public partial class XrmServiceContextr : Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext
Line 192819:    {
Line 192820:        

Source File: c:\Users\Gevor\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestCRM\TestCRM\App_Code\Xrm.cs    Line: 192818
```

**Command line parameters**

> c:\DynamicsCRM\SDK\Bin>CrmSvcUtil.exe /out:Xrm.cs
>   /url:https://Organization/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
>   /domain:DOMAIN /username:USERNAME /password:PASSWORD /namespace:Xrm
>   /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContextr
>   /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If System.Data.Services is not the GAC, it neeeds to be merged in your assembly, not only referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a System.Data.Services reference to your TestCRM application.

Comment: All needed references already attached (System.Data.Services attached too)